# Whitelisting app to render html with private vimeo links

Tags: html, video, vimeo

I have native app that gets html from the database, and renders it. I can embed a vimeo link with no problem. I need to be able to get access to a private vimeo account that whitelists domains. What domain should I whitelist since this is a native app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the Player with a webview or in-app browser, there's no HTTP referer passed back to the Player iframe. Without an HTTP referer, the Player cannot determine if the domain where its embedded is allowed to serve and play the video.

The only workaround is to embed the video on a web page you control, and then open or embed that page in your webview. It's not an elegant solution, but it will allow usage of a domain-restricted Vimeo Player in a webview.

Alternatively, if you're writing a native app use the direct video file links with the app platform's native media player; this feature is only available to PRO and Business users: https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224823567-Direct-links